# parsing text from xml based tag

Tags: android, arrays, xml-parsing

I want to display text from xml based on index array, but I am confused to make the array.

```
String [] textExmple={R.};// This is the array I want to create
```

this sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<country id="2">
    <name>
        Australia
    </name>
    <capital>
        Canberra
    </capital>
</country>

<country id="3">
    <name>
        USA
    </name>
    <capital>
        Washington, D.C.
    </capital>
</country>
```

Comment: what text are you trying to extract into an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple regex match and extract the array

`string text = "xmlstring"`
`string[] arr = text.match(/>[a-z]+<\//gi)`

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: This will give you all text from xml in array format. Here it would be ["Australia","Canberra"..]